# Custom Fyne Adaptive Grid Layout

Tags: go, fyne

I'm modifying container.NewAdaptiveGrid() of fyne library in a way that we render widgets's width according the ratio slice we pass. As of now, container.NewAdaptiveGrid()  renders widgets of equal width in a row. basically (total row size / now of widgets).

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/theme"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func New(layout fyne.Layout, objects ...fyne.CanvasObject) *fyne.Container {
    return fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout, objects...)
}

func NewAdaptiveGridWithRatios(ratios []float32, objects ...fyne.CanvasObject) *fyne.Container {
    return New(NewAdaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios(ratios), objects...)
}

// Declare conformity with Layout interface
var _ fyne.Layout = (*adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios)(nil)

type adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios struct {
    ratios          []float32
    adapt, vertical bool
}

func NewAdaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios(ratios []float32) fyne.Layout {
    return &adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios{ratios: ratios, adapt: true}
}

func (g *adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios) horizontal() bool {
    if g.adapt {
        return fyne.IsHorizontal(fyne.CurrentDevice().Orientation())
    }

    return !g.vertical
}

func (g *adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios) countRows(objects []fyne.CanvasObject) int {
    count := 0
    for _, child := range objects {
        if child.Visible() {
            count++
        }
    }

    return int(math.Ceil(float64(count) / float64(len(g.ratios))))
}

// Get the leading (top or left) edge of a grid cell.
// size is the ideal cell size and the offset is which col or row its on.
func getLeading(size float64, offset int) float32 {
    ret := (size + float64(theme.Padding())) * float64(offset)

    return float32(ret)
}

// Get the trailing (bottom or right) edge of a grid cell.
// size is the ideal cell size and the offset is which col or row its on.
func getTrailing(size float64, offset int) float32 {
    return getLeading(size, offset+1) - theme.Padding()
}

// Layout is called to pack all child objects into a specified size.
// For a GridLayout this will pack objects into a table format with the number
// of columns specified in our constructor.
func (g *adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios) Layout(objects []fyne.CanvasObject, size fyne.Size) {
    rows := g.countRows(objects)
    cols := len(g.ratios)
    if g.horizontal() {
        cols = rows
        rows = len(g.ratios)
    }

    padWidth := float32(cols-1) * theme.Padding()
    padHeight := float32(rows-1) * theme.Padding()
    var totalRatio float32
    for _, r := range g.ratios {
        totalRatio += r
    }

    cellWidth := (float64(size.Width) - float64(padWidth)) / float64(len(g.ratios))
    cellHeight := float64(size.Height-padHeight) / float64(rows)

    if !g.horizontal() {
        cellWidth, cellHeight = cellHeight, cellWidth
        cellWidth = float64(size.Width-padWidth) / float64(rows)
        cellHeight = float64(size.Height-padHeight) / float64(len(g.ratios))
    }

    row, col := 0, 0
    i := 0
    for _, child := range objects {
        if !child.Visible() {
            continue
        }

        //ratio := g.ratios[j%len(g.ratios)]
        cellSize := fyne.NewSize(float32(cellWidth)*g.ratios[i], float32(cellHeight))

        x1 := getLeading(float64(cellSize.Width), col)
        y1 := getLeading(float64(cellSize.Height), row)
        x2 := getTrailing(float64(cellSize.Width), col)
        y2 := getTrailing(float64(cellSize.Height), row)
        fmt.Println("1s :", x1, y1)
        fmt.Println("2s :", x2, y2)
        child.Move(fyne.NewPos(x1, y1))
        child.Resize(cellSize)

        if g.horizontal() {
            if (i+1)%cols == 0 {
                row++
                col = 0
            } else {
                col++
            }
        } else {
            if (i+1)%cols == 0 {
                col++
                row = 0
            } else {
                row++
            }
        }
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println("i :", i)
}

func (g *adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios) MinSize(objects []fyne.CanvasObject) fyne.Size {
    minSize := fyne.NewSize(0, 0)
    return minSize
}

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("My Windows")
    myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(600, 200))

    button1 := widget.NewButton("Button 1", func() {
        // Handle button click for button 1
    })

    button2 := widget.NewButton("Button 2", func() {
        // Handle button click for button 2
    })
    button1.Importance = widget.WarningImportance
    button2.Importance = widget.DangerImportance
    title := widget.NewLabelWithStyle("Custom", fyne.TextAlignCenter, fyne.TextStyle{Bold: true})

    myWindow.SetContent(container.NewVBox(title,
        NewAdaptiveGridWithRatios([]float32{0.3, 0.7}, button1, button2)))

    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

I expected buttons to be side by side where relative width of the buttons are in ration 3:7. But I'm getting 2 horizontal line one below another.
I'm modifying : https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/blob/8c2509518b2df442a6b748d9b07754739592e6d7/layout/gridlayout.go
to make my custom one.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/theme"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func New(layout fyne.Layout, objects ...fyne.CanvasObject) *fyne.Container {
    return fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout, objects...)
}

func NewAdaptiveGridWithRatios(ratios []float32, objects ...fyne.CanvasObject) *fyne.Container {
    return New(NewAdaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios(ratios), objects...)
}

// Declare conformity with Layout interface
var _ fyne.Layout = (*adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios)(nil)

type adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios struct {
    ratios          []float32
    adapt, vertical bool
}

func NewAdaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios(ratios []float32) fyne.Layout {
    return &adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios{ratios: ratios, adapt: true}
}

func (g *adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios) horizontal() bool {
    if g.adapt {
        return fyne.IsHorizontal(fyne.CurrentDevice().Orientation())
    }

    return !g.vertical
}

func (g *adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios) countRows(objects []fyne.CanvasObject) int {
    count := 0
    for _, child := range objects {
        if child.Visible() {
            count++
        }
    }

    return int(math.Ceil(float64(count) / float64(len(g.ratios))))
}

// Layout is called to pack all child objects into a specified size.
// For a GridLayout this will pack objects into a table format with the number
// of columns specified in our constructor.
func (g *adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios) Layout(objects []fyne.CanvasObject, size fyne.Size) {

    rows := g.countRows(objects)
    cols := len(g.ratios)

    padWidth := float32(cols-1) * theme.Padding()
    padHeight := float32(rows-1) * theme.Padding()
    tGap := float64(padWidth)
    tcellWidth := float64(size.Width) - tGap
    cellHeight := float64(size.Height-padHeight) / float64(rows)

    fmt.Println(cols, rows)
    fmt.Println(cellHeight, tcellWidth+tGap, tGap)
    fmt.Println("tcellWidth, cellHeight", tcellWidth, cellHeight)
    if !g.horizontal() {
        padWidth, padHeight = padHeight, padWidth
        tcellWidth = float64(size.Width-padWidth) - tGap
        cellHeight = float64(size.Height-padHeight) / float64(cols)
    }

    row, col := 0, 0
    i := 0
    var x1, x2, y1, y2 float32 = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
    fmt.Println("padWidth, padHeight, tcellWidth, cellHeight, float32(theme.Padding()):", padWidth, padHeight, tcellWidth, cellHeight, float32(theme.Padding()))
    for _, child := range objects {
        if !child.Visible() {
            continue
        }

        if i == 0 {
            x1 = 0
            y1 = 0
        } else {
            x1 = x2 + float32(theme.Padding())*float32(1)
            y1 = y2 - float32(cellHeight)
        } // float32(tGap/float64(col))
        //  (size + float64(theme.Padding())) * float64(offset)  float32(theme.Padding())*float32(1)
        x2 = x1 + float32(tcellWidth*float64(g.ratios[i]))
        y2 = float32(cellHeight)

        fmt.Println("x1,y1 :", x1, y1)
        fmt.Println("x2, y2 :", x2, y2)
        fmt.Println("eff width", tcellWidth*float64(g.ratios[i]))

        fmt.Println("------")
        child.Move(fyne.NewPos(x1, y1))
        child.Resize(fyne.NewSize((x2 - x1), y2-y1))

        if g.horizontal() {
            if (i+1)%cols == 0 {
                row++
                col = 0
            } else {
                col++
            }
        } else {
            if (i+1)%cols == 0 {
                col++
                row = 0
            } else {
                row++
            }
        }
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println("i :", i)
}

func (g *adaptiveGridLayoutWithRatios) MinSize(objects []fyne.CanvasObject) fyne.Size {
    rows := g.countRows(objects)
    minSize := fyne.NewSize(0, 0)
    for _, child := range objects {
        if !child.Visible() {
            continue
        }

        minSize = minSize.Max(child.MinSize())
    }

    if g.horizontal() {
        minContentSize := fyne.NewSize(minSize.Width*float32(len(g.ratios)), minSize.Height*float32(rows))
        return minContentSize.Add(fyne.NewSize(theme.Padding()*fyne.Max(float32(len(g.ratios)-1), 0), theme.Padding()*fyne.Max(float32(rows-1), 0)))
    }

    minContentSize := fyne.NewSize(minSize.Width*float32(rows), minSize.Height*float32(len(g.ratios)))
    return minContentSize.Add(fyne.NewSize(theme.Padding()*fyne.Max(float32(rows-1), 0), theme.Padding()*fyne.Max(float32(len(g.ratios)-1), 0)))
}

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("My Windows Custom UI")
    myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(600, 200))

    var buttons [16]*widget.Button

    for i := 0; i < 16; i++ {
        button := widget.NewButton(fmt.Sprintf("Btn %d", i+1), func() {
            // Handle button click for this button
        })

        // Set the button importance based on the button index
        if i%2 == 0 {
            button.Importance = widget.WarningImportance
        } else {
            button.Importance = widget.DangerImportance
        }

        buttons[i] = button
    }

    pgBar := widget.NewLabelWithStyle("Progress :", fyne.TextAlignCenter, fyne.TextStyle{Italic: true})
    progressBar := widget.NewProgressBar()
    progressBar.SetValue(0.95)

    myWindow.SetContent(container.NewVBox(
        NewAdaptiveGridWithRatios([]float32{0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1}, buttons[0], buttons[1], buttons[2], buttons[3]),
        NewAdaptiveGridWithRatios([]float32{0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4}, buttons[4], buttons[5], buttons[6], buttons[7]),
        NewAdaptiveGridWithRatios([]float32{0.6, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1}, buttons[8], buttons[9], buttons[10], buttons[11]),
        NewAdaptiveGridWithRatios([]float32{0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1}, buttons[12], buttons[13], buttons[14], buttons[15]),
        NewAdaptiveGridWithRatios([]float32{0.1, 0.9}, pgBar, progressBar),
    ))

    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

I've added multiple buttons and other widgets in different ratios.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When debugging your own widget or layout it is easier to eliminate all other items from the window. In this case the VBox may be compressing things vertically so remove that and continue to work on your code until it does what you expect.

On the face of it I expect that `countRows` is not doing what you expect.